# Error when trying to send to Outlook Contact Group using Python

Tags: python, outlook

I need to send some emails with attachments to different contact groups using python and outlook. The Contact Group I created is called 'Test'. It will not send the emails to 'Test' outlook Contact Group.

Error message when I run my code:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 11, in 
    send_notification(i)

File "", line 10, in send_notification
    mail.send

File "C:\Users\thisguy\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 516, in **getattr**
    ret = self.*oleobj*.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Outlook does not recognize one or more names. ', None, 0, -2147467259), None)

```
import win32com.client as win32
import psutil
import os
import subprocess
import glob




brands = ['PM', 'KP', 'SW', 'GM']

morning = '<p>Good Morning,</p>'                    

# Drafting and sending email notification to senders. You can add other senders' email in the list
def send_notification(i):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = 'Test' # Contact Group I want to send the email to
    mail.Subject = 'Expenses'
    mail.Attachments.Add(Source = 'c:/users/thisguy/desktop/Expenses.docx')
    for f in glob.glob('c:/users/thisguy/desktop/'+ i +' Expense*.xlsx'):
        mail.Attachments.Add(Source = f)
    mail.HTMLBody =  morning          
    mail.send

# Open Outlook.exe. Path may vary according to system config
# Please check the path to .exe file and update below

def open_outlook():
    try:
        subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE'])
        os.system("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE");
    except:
        print("Outlook didn't open successfully")

# Checking if outlook is already opened. If not, open Outlook.exe and send email
for item in psutil.pids():
    p = psutil.Process(item)
    if p.name() == "OUTLOOK.EXE":
        flag = 1
        break
    else:
        flag = 0

if (flag == 1):
    for i in brands:
        send_notification(i)
else:
    open_outlook()
    for i in brands:
        send_notification(i)
```

Comment: Does your code work if, instead of sending to a group 'Test', you try to send to a single email address?

Comment: Yes, it works in that case. I can't figure out how to send it to an Outlook Contact Group.

Comment: Ok, I finally got the same error than you. The name 'Test' is already used in my contact in Outlook and I'm not sure by defining yourself a group with this name will work. Try to change the name of your group in outlook, like 'test_expenses', and run your code with the new name?

Comment: @Ben.T Solution Verified. Thank you!